# How to monitor the progress of model

Tags: r, analytics

I am training a bootstrapped model having data frame 891 * 17

`CtrlBoot <- trainControl(method = "boot", number = 1000)
modelC50_titanic <- train(as.factor(Survived) ~., data = train, trControl = CtrlBoot, mrthod = "C5. 0")`

How much time it will take to train the model? It is running from last one hour, is there any way to track the progress of completion ?

**PC configurations**
RAM: 4GB
Processor: i3@2.10GHz
HDD: 512GB
OS: Windows 7
Platform: Rstudio

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no way to do this in `caret`. If it takes too long then you'll need to change something to make it faster. By the way, I don't think that `mrthod` is a valid option. Also, "C5.0" does have a reputation for being intractably slow.

Comment: Well there isn't a verbose option for C5.0 in `caret` but why did you set the  resampling iterations to 1000 when the default is 25? That is tremendous overkill and is going to kill your performance.

Comment: C5.0 on the command line does have an option for this (tailing a temp file). I haven't looked at the R implementation to see if the authors included the same temp-file creation but you could take a look. Even hinting that this is a `caret` deficiency is ludicrous and misrepresentative, though. `caret` normalizes the interface to various computational models in various packages. Some of them have progress output, some don't.

Comment: You may consider Hadoop with R to break your job into smaller chunks and take advantage of the multiple cores on your CPU. Thats another option to speed up Machine Learning data crunching.